# Want to make VSCode always start with `--disable-gpu` option, from everywhere, e.g. gnome dock

Tags: nvidia, gnome, 18.04, configuration, visual-studio-code

Is there a config file like `.vscoderc` or something I can use to persistently store the `--disable gpu` flag, such that vscode always starts with this flag enabled, no matter from where (or from which wrapper-script) it was launched?

Background: I have two older (fanless) NVidia GPUs in my PC. And I've noticed that VScode behaves weirdly on my PC after a while. (This happened after an upgrade to 18.04, which is generally problematic with NVidia cards + proprietary drivers but I didn't know this beforehand)

Therefore, I want to *always* start VSCode with the `--disable-gpu` command line flag enabled. I can do this from the command line, sure. But what about configuring the dock/launcher icon and what about the "default editor" settings that are hidden deeply inside gnome somewhere? (VSCode comes up when I have to edit a `git merge` message for instance.)

Answer (score 3):

Find `*.desktop` file and edit it.
The file should be `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/`

Add parameter to the line `Exec=`

Comment: Mine are in `~/Desktop` and I've already edited them accordingly. But I don't think that this is sufficient.

Comment: Gnome look for `.desktop` in those 2 locations and if there is something this will be shown in dash/dock. `~/Desktop` is omitted by gnome.
So, you have to edit `.desktop` file in those 2 location to see changes.